# What variable can I use which I can set its set of values?

Tags: java, variables

I want to use a variable that can only have a set amount of values that I define in Java. I've seen this variable before but I cannot find it online any where. For example, I make it so it can be either WIN, LOSE or TIE. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You need to create an enum, one with those three items or *states*.

```
public enum GameResult {
  WIN, LOSE, TIE
}
```

Thus if you create a GameResult variable, it can have only one of four possible states, null or one of the three states above:

```
private GameResult gameResult;  // at present it is null

// later in your code:
gameResult = GameResult.WIN;
```

Note also that enums can have fields and methods which can be quite useful as well.

e.g.,

```
public enum GameResult {
  WIN(1), LOSE(-1), TIE(0);

  private int score;
  // a private constructor!
  private GameResult(int score) {
     this.score = score;
  }

  public int getScore() {
     return score;
  }
}
```